# Problema con jquery datatables

Tags: html, jquery, datatables, plugin

Tengo un problema con el responsive design del plugin DataTables de JQuery. Lo que necesito es lo siguiente:

Tenemos el siguiente aspecto cuando se hace responsive al navegador:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Claro, el problema es que cuando en ese momento marco el checkbox, se me abre el modal de detalles (ya que es como si estsuviera dando al "+"), y en el modal de los detalles no me aparece el checkbox marcado.

Lo que buscaba es cambiar el orden de la columna en el responsive, es decir, que el "+" aparezca en la columna de Id.Pieza, y no en la columna del checkbox.

¿Esto es posible?¿Cómo?
He probado a reordenar las columnas con `colReorder: {order: [4 , 3, 2, 1, 0] },` pero tampoco funciona.

Saludos.

---

Este es el código de configuración del datatable. Si hace falta cualquier otro código me decís, ya que es un portal web y es enorme.

// DATATABLES

```
    var table = $('#tablaDatos').DataTable({
        ajax: {             
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'datos.php',
                    processing: true,
                    data: function ( d ) {
                      return $.extend( {}, d, {
                          //
                      });
                    }
                },
                deferRender: true,
                columns: [
                    {data:
                        function (data, type, row, meta) {
                            return '<input type="checkbox" name="losCheckboxes"  value="'+data.idPieza+'" style="display: inline;" />';

                        }
                    },
                    {data:"idPieza"},
                    {data:"numSerie"},
                    {data:"codigo"},
                    {data:"nombreAlmacen"},
                    {data:"estadoPieza"},
                    {data:"nombreProyecto"},
                    {data:"nombreProveedor"},
                    {data:"observaciones"},
                    {data:"descripArticulo"},
                    {data: 
                        function (data, type, row, meta) {
                            return '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">Añadir Observaciones</button>';    
                        }
                    }
                ],
                order: [[ 1, "asc" ]],
                columnDefs: [
                    { "orderable": false, "targets": 0 },
                    { "orderable": true, "targets": 1 },
                    { "orderable": false, "targets": 2 },
                    { "orderable": false, "targets": 3 },
                    { "orderable": false, "targets": 4 },


{ "visible": false, "targets": 4 },
                { "orderable": false, "targets": 5 },
                { "orderable": false, "targets": 6 },
                { "orderable": false, "targets": 7 },
                { "orderable": false, "targets": 8 },
                { "orderable": false, "targets": 9 },
                { "orderable": false, "targets": 10 }
            ],
            autoWitdh: false,
            pagingType: "full",
            responsive: true,
            colReorder: {order: [4 , 3, 2, 1, 0] },
            autoWidth: false,
            searching: false,
            dom: 'Bfrtip',
            lengthChange: false,
            buttons: [],                
            "oLanguage": {  
                "sProcessing": "Procesando...",
                "sLengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ registros:",
                "sZeroRecords": "No se encontraron resultados.",
                "sInfo": "Mostrando _START_ a _END_ de _TOTAL_ registros.",
                "sInfoEmpty": "Mostrando desde 0 hasta 0 de 0 registros",
                "sInfoFiltered": "(filtrado de _MAX_ registros en total)",
                "sInfoPostFix": "",
                "sSearch": "Buscar:",
                "sUrl": "",
                "oPaginate": {
                "sFirst": "Primero",
                "sPrevious": "&laquo;",
                "sNext": "&raquo;",
                "sLast": "Último"}
            }
        });
```

Comment: Hola Marcos, por favor, trata de crear un [mcve] para que podamos ver el problema funcionando y que sea más fácil ayudarte.

Comment: Puedes poner tu codigo. Asi seria mas facil ayudarte